# How to take the values using data-list but values is already selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, datalist, html-datalist

Here i am using data-list i have one URL in that i am passing areaId= 2 & areaName = Chennai,Now i have to take the values and i want to make that value is selected,and again i want to change the areaName so i am changing instead of Chennai , i changed Karur means finally i am clicking submit button means i want to take the areaId & areaName

```js
 $('.options').on('change', function() {
     var city_id = $('#options option[value="' + $('#location12').val() + '"]').data('id');
  $('#city_id').val(city_id);
  console.log(city_id);
  
});


function myFunction (){
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST">
<input list="options" type="name" class="form-control options" style="border-radius:0px;height: 36px;" name="location12" id="location12" placeholder="City" rel='<?php echo $_GET['areaId']?>' value='<?php echo $_GET['areaName']?>'>
 <datalist id="options">
 <option data-id="1" value="Bangalore"></option>
 <option data-id="2" value="Chennai"></option>
 <option data-id="3" value="Karur"></option>
 </datalist>
<input type="hidden" name="city_id" id="city_id">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Tip: You don't have to set values for the `<input>`. You have to set the `<option>` instead to be *selected*.

Answer (score 0):

you have 3 options there, either use the default PHP value to set the text input value and dynamically set the `city_id` value on load/ready with JS, do the contrary and set the datalist corresponding option with adding `selected="selected"` in PHP and update the text input on load, or finally set them both in PHP.

here is the most simple case for PHP: setting the text input value and update `city_id`. For the second solution there is a bit more code as you have to test the options and add `selected="selected"` manually if the good one. I would personnally prefer the second because your PHP value will actually be verified against the options so that nothing will be selected if PHP value is wrong and does not correspond to any option value.

```js
 $('.options').on('change', function() {
     var city_id = $('#options option[value="' + $('#location12').val() + '"]').data('id');
  $('#city_id').val(city_id);
  console.log(city_id);
  
});

//setting one of the element value based on the other's default value:
$(document).ready(function(){
    //use this to set text input based on default selected option
    //$('#location12').val($('#options option:selected').val());
    //console.log('text input is now: ' + $('#location12').val());
    
    //or this for the other way round
    $('#city_id').val($('#options option[value="' + $('#location12').val() + '"]').data('id'));
    console.log('city_id is now: ' + $('#city_id').val());
});


function myFunction (){
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST">
<input list="options" type="name" class="form-control options" style="border-radius:0px;height: 36px;" name="location12" id="location12" placeholder="City" rel="<?php echo $_GET['areaId']?>" value="Karur">
 <datalist id="options">
 <option data-id="1" value="Bangalore"></option>
 <option data-id="2" value="Chennai" selected="selected"></option>
 <option data-id="3" value="Karur"></option>
 </datalist>
<input type="hidden" name="city_id" id="city_id">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Bro i need rel attribute value, how can get?

Comment: i don't see what you mean, can you be more precise?

Comment: City Id we getting now, how can we get city name like Bangalore or Chennai

Comment: in my example i set the `location12` value to Kajur for it to work, but if you want to use PHP's value to set the default like in the example, you should keep `<?php echo $_GET['areaName']?>` here. For the city name there is nothing more to do to pass it to the form submission, it will be added to the data as `location12`